# How to list all the files of a directory which is on a remote machine in java?

Tags: java

I have a c code.I need to write a java code which i would then have to convert into a jar file and run from my c code.The purpose of the jar file would be to log into a remote machine and then navigate to a defined path and then list all the files in the specific directory in string format.That is i want to obtain something like 
String FileNames[] = {"File1","File2",...} so that then i can use the system call available for FTP log in and download to download all the files recursively.

So how do i do that.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apache [commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/), which contains FTP utilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, take a look at it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void recursive_file(String path) {
File theFolder = new File(path);
File temp;
String[] theFiles = path.list();

for (int i=0; i<theFiles.length; i++) {
    theFiles[i]=path+theFiles[i];
    temp=new File(theFiles[i]);
    if (temp.isDirectory()) {
        recursive_file(theFiles[i]);
        }
    else { list.add(theFiles[i]); 
         }
    }
}
```

Something like this? Not sure it's the most elegant solution. You might also need to append a "/" or "\" on your path String depending on how it's given to the method.